# Pytest: When writing many assert statements in the same test function, some of it fails, but how to know which assert statement/s is causing failure?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

Test file :

```
from RansomNote import Solution


def test_canConstruct():
    sol = Solution()
    assert sol.canConstruct('aa', 'aab') == True
    assert sol.canConstruct('xx','aaabc') == True
    assert sol.canConstruct('aab','ababa') == True
```

Ouput after running pytest -v :

```
==================================================================== short test summary info =====================================================================
FAILED Easy/test_ransomNote.py::test_canConstruct - AssertionError: assert False == True
======================================================================= 1 failed in 0.01s
```

QUESTION :
First of all, is it ok to have many assert statements in the same test function or is it not recommended?
In output it just says assertion error, how to know which assert statement is actually causing the failure?
Is it better to create a new test function for each assert statement?

Tried pytest -v
Expected which assert statement caused the failure.
Output result :
FAILED Easy/test_ransomNote.py::test_canConstruct - AssertionError: assert False == True

Comment: This is a short failure summary, you have detailed failure for every test showing you the context. Regarding multiple assertions in the same question, it is a matter of preference.

Comment: If the assert statements test the same concept (for example attributes of the same object), then it is OK to have multiple assert statements in a test function. However if they check different things, then it is better to split the test function into multiple test functions with a single assertion.

Comment: Diego gave the mic drop answer, but you can also control the amount of failure context using the `--tb` switch. For example, `pytest --tb=no` or `pytest --tb=short` or `pytest --tb=long`

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameters

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y", (("aa", "aab"), ("xx", "aaabc"), ("aab", "ababa")))
def test_canConstruct(x, y):
    sol = Solution()
    assert sol.canConstruct(x, y) is True
```

and get the results individually

```
x.py::test_canConstruct[aa-aab] PASSED                 [ 33%]
x.py::test_canConstruct[xx-aaabc] PASSED               [ 66%]
x.py::test_canConstruct[aab-ababa] PASSED              [100%]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pytest will print a string that follows the assert, so you could do this:

```
from RansomNote import Solution


def test_canConstruct():
    sol = Solution()
    assert sol.canConstruct('aa', 'aab') == True, 'first one failed'
    assert sol.canConstruct('xx','aaabc') == True, 'second one failed'
    assert sol.canConstruct('aab','ababa') == True, 'third one failed'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something missing from your output.

If I try to reproduce your issue using this code:

```
def working_function():
    return True


def failing_function():
    return False


def test_some_function():
    assert working_function()
    assert failing_function()
```

Running `pytest -v` shows clearly which assert statement is failing:

```
================================================================= FAILURES ==================================================================
____________________________________________________________ test_some_function _____________________________________________________________

    def test_some_function():
        assert working_function()
>       assert failing_function()
E       assert False
E        +  where False = failing_function()

test_assert.py:11: AssertionError
========================================================== short test summary info ==========================================================
FAILED test_assert.py::test_some_function - assert False
============================================================= 1 failed in 0.01s =============================================================
```

---

Note also that this:

```
assert working_function()
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
assert working_function() == True
```

That is, there's no reason to include the `== True` in your `asssert` statements.